# Salvaging a failed upgrade from 1404. to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I tried to do the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 and it all went pear shaped. I could not get backup to work on the old one so no backup. I tried all the edits from the command prompt but it keeps giving me "e" is not available or `dpkg` has to be configured manually. I give up on this, so cut and run is my way back. I have Windows 8 installed on a dual boot so its way over my head to fix.

I have installed a 16.04 on a small 250gig sata hd from an old laptop inside my PC. My question is this what files should I save from the old HD. I can still access "as a HD within my new 16.04 small hd" but not boot and save before formatting the failed HD and reinstalling a new 16.04. I obviously tried and got some picture, video and music files some were said to be locked in the old HD. Is there anything I need to take from the old HD that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: I see this is being seen can no one give me a clue what I should save from the old installation?

Comment: From which release did you upgrade? 14.04 or 14.10?